# Is there cleartool command available to find whether a file is symlink or element?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am trying to checkout file using Cleartool co command . If a file is symlink it fails as

> cleartool: Error: Not an element:

Due to this my checkout action fails . I want to avoid that. I want to check whether the file is symlink before checkout. Is there a cleartool command available to find whether a file is symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article "[Symbolic links in snapshot views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_symlinks_ssv.htm)" provide some context to the error message:

> You cannot check out a file element from a symbolic link path; you must check out the link target.

You will find more in "[About checking out Symbolic Link (symlink) Targets in dynamic views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146295)"

> In a snapshot view, the symbolic link target must be loaded in your view also, in order for the Symlink Target Operations to appear.
>   However, these options are limited, such as the checkout does not work, and the alternatives are to either Warp To Symlink Target or use a dynamic view.

So:

> I want to check whether the file is symlink before checkout.

Considering [`cleartool ln`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm), [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), I would do before a checkout:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[slink_text]p" myFile
```

That will display the **arget of symbolic link**, as displayed by `cleartool ls`.

If the result is empty, it is not a symlink.

Comment: Thanks . I wrote that command as powershell function and works